# Result after find query in mongodb not produced

Tags: javascript, sails.js, sails-mongo

After running the code, it shows "products is not defined".Where products is supposed to be result of find() query in "products" collection in mongodb. When I run the same query outside the loop, it shows the desired result. How to solve the problem.

```
 Likes.find({"user_id": data.user_id},function(err, likes) {
                    if(likes === undefined) return res.notFound();
                    if (err) return next(err);

                    likedProducts = likes;

                for(var key in likedProducts)
                {
                    product_ids = likedProducts[key]['product_id'];
                    console.log(product_ids);
                    Products.find({"_id": product_ids},myCallback(err,products));
                }

                // return res.json(200, {'success': true, 'count': countNo, 'data': productDetails});  

                function myCallback(err, product_found) {
                        if(product_found === undefined) return res.notFound();
                        if (err) return next(err);
                        // productDetails = product_found;
                        console.log(product_found);
                    }

                });
```